# How to write a template expanding to multiple elements?

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to write a knockout.js template which should expand into a set of table cells. In other words, something like:

```
<tr>
    <td>Cell one</td>
    <td>Cell two</td>
    <div data-bind="template: ..."></div>
    <td>Cell six</td>
</tr>
<script id="..." type="text/html">
    <td>Cell three</td>
    <td>Cell four</td>
    <td>Cell five</td>
</script>
```

But the div tag isn't allowed in the tr, of course, and I can't figure out any way to coax knockout to replace the div tag with the template expansion, rather than nesting the expansion inside the div.

Anybody know a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the new "containerless" templates like this:

```
<tr>
<td>Cell one</td>
<td>Cell two</td>    
<!-- ko foreach: names -->
    <td>Cell three<span data-bind="text: name"></span></td>
    <td>Cell four</td>
    <td>Cell five</td>
<!-- /ko -->
<td>Cell six</td>
```

with js like this:

```
$(function() {
var viewModel = {
    names: ko.observableArray([ { name: "Bob"}, {name: "John"}])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

});

Here is a jsfiddle that shows it in action: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smichelotti/paBdf/)

Here is a jsfiddle that shows it *without* the foreach: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smichelotti/zXtPW/)

Comment: Thanks! This is _almost_ exactly what I want, and _almost_ working for me... Unfortunately I can't get it to work with a template that's not directly inlined in the comment. In other words `<!-- ko template: {name: blah} -->`... I just get "Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined", although I can't even get it that far in jsfiddle. If I can figure it out is jsfiddle, I'll post a link. If you have an example of a named template, I'd be thrilled. Thanks again!

Comment: Never mind, I did get it working. I'd forgotten to quote the template name in the comment. This is precisely what I needed. Perfect!

Comment: Actually, still a problem... I now have it working in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/As8PP/6/), but the same code in a standalone page doesn't work... Using Chrome 14, the jsfiddle version is fine, but the standalone version results in "HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: DOM Exception 3" for reasons that I don't fully understand. Not a problem with your answer, I just thought I'd post this for anyone coming later...

Comment: Thanks hellige, I was struggling to fix my "Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" issue and your comment showed me the path to inner peace :)